# Access Nested List Item for Functions Applied to a Data Frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to split a string in one column...

```
> df.arpt
          arpt
1    CMH 39402
2    IAH 97571
3    DAL 67191
4    HOU 07614
5    OKC 11127
```

...and break it out into two new columns with a result that looks like this...

```
> df.arpt
          arpt   arptCode    arptID
1    CMH 39402        CMH     39402 
2    IAH 97571        IAH     97571   
3    DAL 67191        DAL     67191
4    HOU 07614        HOU     07614
5    OKC 11127        OKC     11127
```

I really want something like this to be possible...

```
> df.arpt$arptCode <- strsplit(df.arpt$arpt, " ")[[...]][1]
> df.arpt$arptID   <- strsplit(df.arpt$arpt, " ")[[...]][2]
```

... where the `...` in the code represents "for every record in the data frame".

Any suggestions on how to go about this? (I'd like to stick with base R / "out-of-the-box" R rather than higher-level packages.) Am I thinking about this the right way in R?

Answer (score 0):

If the arptCode values are row names, you can convert them into a column.

```
library(tidyverse)
df.arpt %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "arptCode")
```

If they are not row names then you can use `separate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df.arpt %>% 
  separate(arpt, into = c('arptCode', 'aprtID'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm trying to stick with 'base' and 'recommended' packages.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df<-data.frame(arpt =c("CMH 39402", "IAH 97571", "DAL 67191", "HOU 07614", "OKC 11127")) 
tidyr::separate(df, arpt, into = c("artpCode", "arptID"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm trying to stick with 'base' and 'recommended' packages.

Answer (score 0):

Because the strings are all fixed length, I was able to apply the `substr` function instead in order to move past the problem. However, I still don't know what the solution would be if the result of the function was a list.